# Is there any way to check if a value near a certain value is in the keys of the dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to check if a value is near a certain value in the keys of the dictionary.
For example, I have a dictionary temp below and there are 4 keys; 1,10,20,30.
If I code like this, it makes sense.

```
temp = {1:2, 10:4, 20:5, 30:12}
10 in temp.keys()
>> True

15 in temp.keys()
>> False
```

But if I code like this, it shows the result that I didn't anticipate. Becase x+1 is 10 and this value is certainly in the keys of the dictionary.

```
x = 9
(x-2 or x-1 or x or x+1 or x+2) in temp.keys()
>>False
```

Did I miss something? I wonder how to solve this. Please help me
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use **[`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any)**:

```
>>> temp = {1: 2, 10: 4, 20: 5, 30: 12}
>>> x = 9
>>> any(val in temp.keys() for val in (x - 2, x - 1, x, x + 1, x + 2))
True
>>> any(x + dx in temp.keys() for dx in range(-2, 2 + 1))
True
>>> any(val in temp.keys() for val in range(x - 2, x + 3)))
True
```

Comment: Better yet, use `range`.

Comment: `any((val - diff) in temp.keys() for diff in range(-2, 3))`?

Comment: I really appreciate your kind answer. Thanks. It really works!!!

Comment: I was just about to add a range alternative, (maybe not as clean as yours, Chris).

Comment: Fancy schmancy: `not temp.keys().isdisjoint(range(x-2, x+3))`

Answer (score 1):

```
Input: 1 or 2 or 3
Output: 1

Input: 1 and 2 and 3
Output: 3
```

As you can see from the example above. `or` gives the first truthy value and `and` gives the last truthy value.

Issue you have is because of the line:

```
(x-2 or x-1 or x or x+1 or x+2)
```

This line does not acts as the boolean expression. Instead it gives you whatever the value of `x - 2` is. In your case it will be `7`. And `7` is not in the key. So, it's `False`.